# I have a txt file with a list of letters and numbers, and I need to sort it based on the numbers, how do I go about doing this?

Tags: python, list, sorting, text-files

What I have so far is a program that reads a text file, and puts it into a list. The txt file looks like:

`asdf:15.3
eazzz:31.12
qw:1.65
...`

I am kind of new to Python so I'm still trying to figure out how to do this properly. I know this will separate the numbers from the letters, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
def get_num(str):
    items = str.split(':')
    return float(items[1])
```

The desired output will have the numbers sorted out in descending order with their respective letters. I know this can probably be done with "sort" but if possible I'd also like to see it done with for-loops.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use str as the input name.
To sort a list containing tuples `(name, value)` just do the following:

```
sorted(list_name, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)
```

`key = lambda x : x[1]` indicates that you want to sort the list by `value` while `reverse = True` indicates that you want the sort to be in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

```
data  = '''asdf:15.3
eazzz:31.12
qw:1.65
adasf:7.3'''

# convert string to list
lst = data.split('\n')

#sort list of data by two things. first the string part second number part
print '\n'.join(sorted(lst, key=lambda item:(item.split(':')[0],float(item.split(':')[1])), reverse = True))
```

output:

```
qw:1.65
eazzz:31.12
asdf:15.3
adasf:7.3
```